# white background for date picker dialog shadow

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker

I add datepicker to my application but my problem the shadow for the dialog have white background ,  use Android 21 for compile .

please help me to remove white background ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "bug" in your `themes.xml` or `styles.xml` material design support library is not working properly with dialogs.

So remove the specific dialog code or separate it in different versions.

---

Trying to explain a little bit further.

Generally when we extend the original application theme we have an `themes.xml` and/or `styles.xml` files under the `values` folder. In there code you will find something like these:

Application theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... other styling values ...  -->

    <!-- Dialog attributes -->
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/MyTheme.Dialog</item>
    <!-- AlertDialog attributes -->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyTheme.Dialog</item>

    <!-- ... other styling values ...  -->
</style>
```

Custom dialog theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Dialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- some styling values here -->
</style>
```

What needs customization is the `parent` of the `MyTheme.Dialog` this `Theme.`**`AppCompat`**`.Light.Dialog` does not work properly for all android versions it may work for Lollipop but does not work for KitKat, or the opposite.

- With a simple run of the app in each platform you can easily find out in which version it works.
- Then you can create a different folder for `values-v21` and define the parent of the dialog accordingly, so that it work for both versions.

You can apply some other workarounds regarding the customization of the style, in order for this to work.

If you would like further research, or theme customization ideas take a look at the source of android theme.xml [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Added further details on the post. The theme names that I used are just for explaining reason and depends on your code. I hope that now it is more clear the general idea of why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This gave me an idea, although I used some other theme.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem,

**First Solution I have done :**
I end up giving this theme in the DatePickerDialog builder. What's important is the windowBackground set to transparent.

```
<style name="Theme.Yp.DatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

**Second and Final Solution :**
I finished by using the `DatePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` that works just fine. We didn't use a lot of styling so it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

It may be late but will help.

You have to add transparent background of you dialog. Here is how you can do this:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, reservationDate, 2014, 1, 1)
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

for me it didn't help to set the window background to transparent, this made **all** my datePicker dialog with transparent not only the ugly border.. :(

what helped me is to set also the regular background to the color I wanted and the windowBackground to transparent.
this is my style:

```
 <style name="pickerDialogDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/dialogBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorSimpleGreen</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGreen</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSimpleGreen</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">?attr/dialogBackground</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new style in the default style (not style-21)

```
 <style name="Your style" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/app__primary_color</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
 <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, mDateSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparency);
dialog.show();
```