# Android datepicker dialog set background color fails

Tags: java, android

I have the following date picker

```
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
            ctx,
            R.style.DatePicker,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    .....dostuff
                }
            },
            year, month, day);

    dialog.show();
```

In my styles i have setup

```
    <style name="DatePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
```

And my colors

```
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3fb55b</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF247038</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#ece9ea</color>
<color name="colorBackground">#238927</color>
```

But whenever i show the datepicker it always shows a white background as in the following screenshot

[image]

What else do i need to add for the green background to show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [white background for date picker dialog shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919492/white-background-for-date-picker-dialog-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your style.xml file

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">#000 <!--add you backgroud color here --> </item> 
</style>
```

Then :

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
            ctx,
            R.style.DialogTheme,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    .....dostuff
                }
            },
            year, month, day);

    dialog.show();
```

Hope this helps